# A book you wish you could have read before getting started with Math

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, physics, education, book-recommendation

I am pretty sure that there are a lot of knowledgeable and experienced people in the discipline of Math over here. You would have read lots of books to accumulate further learning and perspective regarding Math. Is there a book/books which you wished you could have read before starting to pursue mathematics? A book that would have dramatically changed the way you look at Math if you had a chance to read it before? I found this book for [Physics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3948763003) and hope there is something like this for Math.

Comment: Go for Newton's 'Principia Mathematica' or Euclid's 'Elements'

Comment: That looks like an interesting physics book, and I also have a good impression of that author's "no-nonsense" series.

Comment: @Spectre Newton's Principia Mathematica is very difficult to read! How much time have you spent on it? Would not say it's an efficient way to learn for a beginner.

Comment: Not really in the same scope but AOPS Volume 1 and 2 completely changed the way I looked at math when I was younger

Comment: @littleO I discovered this book after reading the No-nonsense series. I would easily recommend it to anyone with the slightest interest in Physics.

Comment: Maybe "How to Solve It" by Polya is good to read early in one's math education. Just to get the attitude of problem solving and developing problem solving skill from the start.

Comment: @Spectre I once read a crappily translated version of Principia and I don't think it's a good first book.

Comment: @Daniel AOPS books on any topic is a good book in my personal opinion but it is considered as a Textbook. I don't know if it can induce interest in Math like let's say Pólya's "How to Solve It" as mentioned by littleO

Comment: @TikolaNesla , I was a bit of a hypocrite when I suggested 'The Principia' ()... But of course, it is an important book

Comment: @Spectre I could guess it . Just kidding, If it's Physics then I'd suggest Relativity by Einstein cause the amount of curiosity it builds. I haven't found a book yet which matches it. The fact is you don't understand half the book and you get desperate to understand and that is the motivation I was talking about.

Comment: @TikolaNesla , if you are an Indian, I'd suggest going through the guides authored by R.D.Sharma for students upto class 12 .

Comment: @Spectre No clue how you found out I am an Indian but I personally feel RD Sharma is way overhyped. Yes, it's got a heck lota question but what's the point? It fails to deliver the concepts in the way they should be.

Comment: I didn't know that you'd be an Indian, @TikolaNesla ... BTW, the profile name sounds funny ! :)

Comment: But there's something more in R.D.Sharma that's so subtle to be understood

Comment: @Spectre imho, RD Sharma is just a dry textbook with tons of practice exercises (not problems) for Board preparation. I don't understand what place it has here in this discussion

Comment: @Spectre The Indian Education System is highly flawed. They introduce Kinematics in 11th grade which uses Calculus which is taught in 12th grade. To solve those Physics problems, they force you to memorize the main differentiation formulae and expect us to plug the numbers in. Since we don't know any actual Calculus, we tend to mess up those questions hence gradually creating hatred towards Math. PS: Thanks for the compliment regarding the username 

Comment: But whatever be the flaw, we can't but first go with the flow. Once you're out of the water, you can go against the flow, right ?

Comment: @l1mbo Totally agree with you. A dry book would inversely affect a person's interest in my opinion. Especially the ones like RD Sharma and RS Aggarwal.

Comment: @Spectre I don't think Classical Mechanics is a topic which you wanna go with the flow but I can understand what you're trying to tell. RD Sharma is a book that would give a good exercise to your hand but conceptualizing, not so sure.

Comment: @TikolaNesla , that's what we call an achievement ! Without the basics, how come one get into the advanced side ? :)

Comment: @Spectre It's totally alright if we learn Calculus alongside topics in Physics/Chemistry which use them but what happens instead is that we memorize all the formulae for differentiation and integration without any understanding in Kinematics, Thermodynamics, Waves and many more topics before we are even presented with the basic idea of "Slope in a curve".

Comment: I am glad that I bought Thomas Calculus in 11th grade. I flunked up every test in 11th and started scoring better in 12th cause I had good conceptual knowledge. For anyone who's trying to learn Calculus in 11th. Don't use Thomas and instead use Stewart's.

Comment: I am 15 years old..... maybe I can quit this discussion if this is beyond my level ? 

Comment: @Spectre I am 16 years old... *Awkward Silence*

Comment: Writing a story, sir ? :) (on *Awkward silence*)

Comment: @Spectre Well, at least I have made a friend from the internet for the first time who's close to my age. I once found myself flirting with a woman who's 26 y/o. The power of #internet. The emojis says it all.

Comment: BOY ! Don't go for unnecessary stuff ! You'll sink into your vices ! 

Comment: *Awkward Silence continues*

Comment: @Spectre I regret telling that. That's why I changed my username from my real name to TikolaNesla. Nobody can figure out who I really am.

Comment: Ohk...  Well, then, I am off...

Comment: Thanks for knowing that.. I am off.... bye...

Comment: I don't want people whom I dunno to get into my mind.. btw, I forgive you, big bro

Comment: Thanks, lil math bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113709/discussion-between-tikolanesla-and-spectre).

Comment: _Proofs from the book_ is very nice, it points towards a lot of different areas of mathematics that you might want to learn.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting started with math"? I was learning the names of numbers up to nearly 100 before I started school (just before my 7th birthday), but I don't think I ever read an entire math book until I was about 12 years old (Asimov's [**Realm of Numbers**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0395065666); also read first few chapters of Gamow's [**One Two Three** $\ldots$ **Infinity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Two_Three..._Infinity), and parts of other books found in the public library), and all of my 8th grade (age 14) precalculus book, although only half was covered in class.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Not that elementary. Just the philosophy of math for people who are somewhere between Precalc to Calc 2/3 level.

Comment: *between Precal to Cal2/3* --- Then among other books, I'd recommend [**What is Mathematics?**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0195105192) by Courant/Robbins.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks a lot for your suggestion! I'll surely check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great books in this context are in my opinion:

- Fuchs, Tabachnikov: A Mathematical Omnibus
- Arnold: Catastrophe Theory
- Harel: Computers Ltd
- Arnold: Lectures and Problems - A Gift to Young Mathematicians.

Comment: Thank you, @MartinPeters for your opinions!